# Merge two table into one with INSERTED rows NOT OVERWRITE

Tags: google-sheets, merge

I have tried [this example to merge two tables into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364114/merge-multiple-tables) but can't seem to avoid the merged data overwriting existing rows.

Is there a way to make sure, that merged rows are inserted like new rows?
Here's my own [working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o_2EfPqEB3Ux03RSkkb_en7kpE4g6p0DRSuV_VSwPZ8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position staff in row time:

```
={First!A2:F2; array_constrain(sort({Staff!A3:A9,Staff!B3:F9,row(First!A3:A9)-row(First!A1);
FILTER (
{ 
 left(First!A1:A9,0) & First!A1 ,First!B1:F9,row(First!A1:A9)-row(First!A1);
 left(Second!A1:A9,0) & Second!A1 ,Second!B1:F9,row(Second!A1:A9)-row(Second!A1);
 left(Third!A1:A9,0) & Third!A1 ,Third!B1:F9,row(Third!A1:A9)-row(Third!A1);
 left(Fourth!A1:A9,0) & Fourth!A1 ,Fourth!B1:F9,row(Fourth!A1:A9)-row(Fourth!A1)

},
{  
   row(First!A1:A9)-row(First!A1);
   row(Second!A1:A9)-row(Second!A1);
   row(Third!A1:A9)-row(Third!A1);
   row(Fourth!A1:A9)-row(Fourth!A1)
}>1,
   {
     First!A1:A9;
     Second!A1:A9;
     Third!A1:A9;
     Fourth!A1:A9
   }<>"")}   ,7,1),1000,6)}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is excactly what I wanted. Perfect solution.